# How to change THREE.js spinning globe from Canvas to WebGL?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, webgl, renderer

Hi I downloaded the THREE.js globe from this link:
http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_geometry_earth

Now I want to change this entire project from CanvasRenderer to WebGLRenderer because it WebGL loads more segments efficiently and setting a background image is possible using css. In the project I downloaded, I changed this line of code:

```
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
```

To this:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
```

But doing this the globe and the entire scene goes away, all I am left with is a blank page.
How can I change the project to WebGL successfully.

Comment: In three.js r67 with chrome 36.0.1985.125 I get the same result no matter which renderer I use. When you open the javascript console do you get the log message `THREE.WebGLRenderer 67`?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it using r.68, exactly the change as suggested:

```
@@ -105,11 +105,11 @@
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            mesh.position.y = - 250;
            mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
            group.add( mesh );

-           renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
+           renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Works fine for me with Firefox. With Chrome it doesn't work, but it's not the fault of Three.js. If you check your web console you'll find errors like:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at file:///D:/Temp/three.js/examples/textures/land_ocean_ice_cloud_2048.jpg may not be loaded.
```

There should be a command line option you can use to start Chrome with to bypass this security restriction, though I can't readily find what it's called. Also, it's not recommended to browse with that enabled. If you can put the examples on a web server you shouldn't have the problem either.